# Pass correct result out of authentication loop

Tags: python, loops

I am creating a login system which retrieves the details within an entry box and compares it to details on a database. If the details entered are found on the database, the `Bottom()` function is ran. If details are not found, the user is requested to try again.

Currently, the program loops until it is found. However, because I have set up an else statement, if the first item in the database is not the details entered, the `else` section will still run. Is there a way I can change this so that `else` is `else` *and* `last value in the database?`

Here is the function:

```
#Retrieves the information entered into entry box
def Get_Details():
    user_namev2=user_name.get().lower() #Make it so entry box goes red if passwords password is incorrect, and red if username is incorrect/not fault
    user_passwordv2=user_password.get().lower()
    with open ('Accounts.csv', 'r') as Account_file:
        reader = csv.reader(Account_file)
        for row in reader:
            for field in row:
                if row[0] == user_namev2 and row[1] == user_passwordv2:
                    Bottom()
                    break
                else:
                    nomatch_label = Label(canvas, width = 40, height = 2, text = "USERNAME AND PASSWORD NOT FOUND", fg = "red", bg = "gray21", font = font2)
                    canvas_nomatch_label = canvas.create_window(500, 550, window = nomatch_label)
                    name_entry.config(fg = "red")
                    password_entry.config(fg="red")
                    break
```

Comment: Seems like you want `elif` instead of `else`.

Comment: Yeah but what would the elif be

Comment: Would it not make sense to have the function itself loop until correct credentials are supplied, and only then run `Bottom()`?

Comment: Also, rereading the password file every time seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should hopefully work the way you intended, now it loops over the rows and checks username/password against `row[0]` and `row[1]`. If it finds a match it breaks and will not execute the else connected to the for-loop.

Also I removed the for-loop over `row` as the `field` variable wasn't used anyhow.

```
#Retrieves the information entered into entry box
def Get_Details():
    user_namev2=user_name.get().lower() #Make it so entry box goes red if passwords password is incorrect, and red if username is incorrect/not fault
    user_passwordv2=user_password.get().lower()
    with open ('Accounts.csv', 'r') as Account_file:
        reader = csv.reader(Account_file)
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == user_namev2 and row[1] == user_passwordv2:
                Bottom()
                break
        else:
            nomatch_label = Label(canvas, width = 40, height = 2, text = "USERNAME AND PASSWORD NOT FOUND", fg = "red", bg = "gray21", font = font2)
            canvas_nomatch_label = canvas.create_window(500, 550, window = nomatch_label)
            name_entry.config(fg = "red")
            password_entry.config(fg="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Retrieves the information entered into entry box
def Get_Details():
    user_namev2=user_name.get().lower() #Make it so entry box goes red if passwords password is incorrect, and red if username is incorrect/not fault
    user_passwordv2=user_password.get().lower()
    with open ('Accounts.csv', 'r') as Account_file:
        reader = csv.reader(Account_file)
        found = False
        for row in reader:
            for field in row:
                if row[0] == user_namev2 and row[1] == user_passwordv2:
                    Bottom()
                    found = True
                    break

            else:
                if not found:
                    nomatch_label = Label(canvas, width = 40, height = 2, text = "USERNAME AND PASSWORD NOT FOUND", fg = "red", bg = "gray21", font = font2)
                    canvas_nomatch_label = canvas.create_window(500, 550, window = nomatch_label)
                    name_entry.config(fg = "red")
                    password_entry.config(fg="red")
                    break
```

note that the else has been shifted back to pair with the for loop